# TypeScript and Node https.get()

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm starting to convert a project to TypeScript and I'm encountering an error I'm not sure how to solve.

When I write:

```
https.get(`someUrl`, resp => {
  // Define Buffer
  let buffer = '';
  // Fill buffer
  resp.on('')
});
```

It gives me

```
[ts] Parameter 'resp' implicitly has an 'any' type. [7006]
```

I know I can 'fix' it by changing

```
https.get(`someUrl`, resp => {
```

to

```
https.get(`someUrl`, (resp: Object) => {
```

Is this the correct solution? Also, TS has no idea what `resp` actually contains. When I write normal JS it just shows me what methods and props there are but with TS I get nothing. When I get to `resp.on('')` it tells me that `on` does not exist on `Object`. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong? Do I need to write an `interface` for the `https.get` function?

I'm using Visual Studio Code

Is it because I'm using a module that is not intended to be used with TS? I think it could be simply that.

Comment: Do you have `@types/node` installed? `https.get` takes a callback of `(res: http.IncomingMessage) => void`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is this correct?: `"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.19"}`

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the https.get callback function parameter type. Usually it needs to be defined either on the resp type or on the function type, so let's say you create a type T, which you expect to get from the request

```
type ResponseType = { data: any };
```

then you can add to the function call like

```
https.get<ResponseType>(...);
```

or

```
https.get(`someUrl`, (resp: ResponseType) => {...}
```

The object type is quite flexible, and it won't show if you use a property that does not exist on the response type. So I won't use that unless there's no other choice.